# Importing modules in a function

Tags: powershell

I have a .ps1 file with variables I need to import, but I do not know the path at startup and need to import the script within a function. I can verify that the script exists, but none of the variables are imported.

vars.ps1:
    $var1 = 4

```
class Foo
{
    static [string]GetFilename()
    {
        return join-path $path "vars.ps1"
    }
    static [void] ImportScript()
    {
        $settingsFile = GetFilename()
        Import-Module $settingsFile

        write-host "testing settings path $settingsFile : $(Test-Path $settingsFile)"
    }

    static [void] Print()
    {
        $var1= $script:var1
        write-host "var1: $var1"
    }
}
```

output:
    var1:

It seems like there is a limitation to importing modules within functions. I also tried using $global and a regular function instead of a class method but got the same result.

pulling the logic out of the functions and running it at script level works.

Comment: `Import-Module` has a `-Scope {Local | Global}` parameter that might help.

Comment: Adding -Scope Global did not help. I did find out that i can access the imported variables in the function without the script and global qualifiers, so until i find a better method i am going to copy it to a script variable after the import. this only works on the first import unless i add -Force.